# Two way struct pointer link, C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Is it possible to form a two way link between structs? I tried to achieve it like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    b *b;
} a;

typedef struct
{
    int bar;
    a *a;
} b;
```

But the struct a does not know what b is because it's declared afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to reference other structs that may have not been defined up until then, make your declaration like this and it should work:

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    struct b *b;
} a;

typedef struct
{
    int bar;
    struct a *a;
} b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
typedef struct a a;
typedef struct b b;

struct a
{
    int foo;
    b *b;
} ;

struct b
{
    int bar;
    a *a;
} ;
```